# How to enhance Framework7 transitions in Android devices to be more smooth and clean?

Tags: css, cordova, transition, html-framework-7

Framework7 offers good components, like datepicker.
But when navigating or pops the menu up, the transitions are not smooth on Android, especially when using Cordova.
iPhone runs it the same as native.

Maybe there is a fix, or some efficient cordova plugin to install to resolve it to work a little better?

Thanks.

Comment: I have installed crosswalk but its not maintained anymore and it makes the apk weight x2 or even x3 and make 2 different apks - and performances? just 20% better than without crosswalk. Maybe is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one can use custom animation for page transition in framework7 by targetting clases such as .page-from-right-to-center,.page-from-center-to-right like

```
.page-from-right-to-center {
   animation: custom-animation1 ...
}
.page-from-center-to-right {
   animation: custom-animation2 ...
}
.page-from-center-to-left {
   animation: custom-animation3 ...
}
.page-from-left-to-center {
   animation: custom-animation4 ...
}
```

This way one create own custom animation for page transition..

Comment: You have some kind of those custom transitions which are good to use?

Comment: No. I have never used custom animation,since built in is good enough for me. but if you want you use by targeting the mentioned class.

Comment: Built in is good enough for you even when the loaded page is a little "heavy"?

Comment: Yes. are you experiencing any glitch while page transition?

Comment: its slaggy on android, very slaggy, not feel like app at all..
the only reason i keep using it, is because framework7 have very clear usage based on html, and has lots of good features and customizeable, but overall? transitions rate from 0-10? 0. im using samsung galaxy s7 edge (good phone). and i am using it on cordova ofcourse.
whne using this on chrome browser, i rate it 7, but on cordova? its not good.

Comment: are you facing same issue when you view in chrome. if not check if you have used device acceleration for loading percentage. because i have had same problem.

Comment: as i said, in chrome its work good. in cordova app its work bad.
what do you mean by used device acceleration for loading percentage? could you please explain?

Comment: Precise term is hardware acceleration. if you used that. that is one causing problem

Comment: I did not use it.. How can I check if yes?

Comment: which version of F7 are you using for development?

Comment: im using v 1.5.4